# Error saying through repository with belongs_to and has_many relationship entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

We have models below

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
end
```

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :student
```

When we do saving, we use repositories when saving student entities supplied with a verified and existing course_id. However, this throws an error saying "course must exist'
" with the code below

```
 StudentRepository.create(
        id: #generated_id_for_student_entity,
        course_id: #an existing course_id
      )
```

Is there a configuration in our entities or model that allows us to save student through usage of ActiveRecordRepository?